# Получение изображения с веб-камеры с помощью OpenCV в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Интересует, как получить изображение с веб-камеры в `Python 3` с помощью `OpenCV`. В Python 2 получалось сделать вот так:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('output', img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

В третьем питоне просто завершается программа. А во втором исправно выводит изображение. Что не так?

Comment: Есть ли traceback? Включите `-X faulthandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    # cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Опишите словами, в чём вы видите проблему.

Comment: (0) нолик у меня включил камеру, но окошко не выходит, а нет. выходит.)

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Где `(0)` - для встроенной камеры, `(1)` - для внешней.

Comment: Так, на всякий случай... Внешняя камера может быть и (1), и (2), и (3)...